# How do I make "msg.content" constantly get new strings added to it instead of replaced?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, openai-api, gpt-3

```
 var collector = new MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, {
    max: 10,
    time: 60000,
})

        collector.on("collect", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg.content)
            
        openai.Completion.create({
            
            engine: "davinci",
            prompt: msg.content,
            temperature: 0.9,
            max_tokens: 150,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.35,
            presence_penalty: 0.6, 
            stop: ["\n", " Human:", " AI:"]  
        
        }).then((response) => {
            
            message.channel.send(response.choices[0].text)
        })

    })
}
```

So I was trying to implement the AI "GPT-3" into a discord bot to see how it would work, but GPT-3 needs to know the prompt (basically context of a conversation) all the time. With the way I have it set up, it constantly replaces the variable (msg.content) with new strings once they are grabbed by "MessageCollector". I need to make it so that whenever a message is detected, it adds that string to the variable and constantly doing that until, lets say a timer goes off.

Comment: Have a variable that holds all the data and just concat `msg.content` onto it on each `.on('collect')`

Comment: @Elitezen How would I do that? Would I need to make an array of some sort? Sorry I am fairly new to concatenation in this degree.

Comment: `var strdata = strdata + msg.content;`